# Unable to click dropdown from combo box

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

Using : Cucumber Watir / Web Driver

I am trying to click the drop-down element or any element that will open the list.

My error is:

> undefined method `click' for # (NoMethodError)

My Watir code is:

```
@browser.divs(:class => 'dd-field').click  #I have tried other Class names from the html. Can’t get it to click
```

My HTML ( That is highlighted per firebug ):

```html
<div class="header">Deposit•to</div>
<div class="dropdown" ng-class="secondaryClass()">
<div class="dd-field" on="!selectedAccount" ng-switch="">
-- ngSwitchWhen: false -->
<!-- ngSwitchDefault: -->
<div class="dd-label ng-scope" ng-switch-default="">Select•an•account</div>
<div class="dd-arrow-box">
<div class="dd-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

I tried Fire on event click without success.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because you are using `@browser.divs` instead of `@browser.div`, notice one is plural `divs`, which returns a list of `<div>` elements, so no wonder you can't click a list of elements.

Try use `@browser.div` instead, which returns one single element and you should be able to click.

```
@browser.div(:class => 'dd-field').click
```

Comment: @user3233238: Since you're a new user and never accepted any answers before. Just so you know if this answer fixes your issue, please accept it. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697) Otherwise provide some feedback here.